# Are virtual servers like Tor Cloud less advisable?

Tags: security, tor-cloud, ec2

It's probably not difficult to extract Tor encryption keys from storage or memory on virtual hardware like [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) instances. Similar issues likely exist for rented physical servers with management access.

Does this make running Tor Cloud bridges less advisable than running a bridge or relay on your own hardware?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in a sense they are less secure since it's probably trivial, given sufficient access, to copy the system.  Real hardware requires physical access and is, perhaps, easier to detect: an extended and/or unexplained downtime would probably be noticed.

However, diversity is very important for the Tor network.

Therefore, if the choice is between a bridge or relay on a virtual/cloud service on the one hand and no relay on the other hand, I'd argue that having the relay wins.